# Prevent terminal from opening up as maximized/full screen

Tags: command-line

I customized my terminal a little to display an ansi banner when I opened it. But, seemingly randomly, it started opening as full screen. Is there any way I can prevent this/disable it?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: which Ubuntu version, which terminal emulator, provide any details specific to your system. Use "edit" to add any information and clarity to the question. Do not use comments for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said which terminal you are using or even which version of Ubuntu you are using but assuming default gnome-terminal then you can use command line options to set the size and position of the window. See:

`gnome-terminal  --help-window-options`

Specifically:

`--geometry=GEOMETRY`
`Set the window size; for example: 80x24, or 80x24+200+200 (COLSxROWS+X+Y)`

Comment: I'm using zsh. My profile says that the initial terminal size is 80 col by 40 row, yet when I open a new terminal it is full screen.

Comment: I tried your command but it didn't help.